# Dividing people in to groups based on strength and rank

Tags: excel, automation

Edited:
after using Solver which Saulo Suggested I have managed to get excel sorting them in to groups up to 8 groups of 3. though am approaching troubles when going further ideally at this time I need to be able to do 18 groups of 3. but even with the same settings obviously adjusting for the increase in groups excel seems to belly up on the process and fails, any suggestions to adapt to this?

I am trying to figure out an easy and as accurate as possible without going too crazy with the math and formulas as I am basic with my excel coding (coding in general) to calculate the ideal groups of 3 based on rank and strength for a video game.

I want to pair the strongest with the weakest and then fill the gaps evenly for the 3rd person. so, that each team’s overall strength is the same roughly.

factors I have is a designated leader(rank) and an overall power level(strength).

doing this manually isn't too hard but trying to automate it is. any thoughts or suggestions would be amazing!?

something like this but automated which is where I am getting stuck, as I want to be able to add more players and adjust strengths as they come along.
[image]

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Posting a sample of your data and the outcome would be helpful.

Comment: Just uploaded a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Jordan, you have a classic situation to use "Solver". First of all, you have to make "Solver available in your Excel. Select Home -> Option -> Supplements -> Solver.  Then, the solver button´s will be at the "Data" menu.

Solver is about solving a problem with especific conditions, changing specific cell, with specifc purpose. In your case, your purpose is creat teams with the minimal strength diference. A condition of your problem is that teams should have the same number of players. See how I organized the sheet.

[Sheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3jqiLgJGDfIdXpLajVVOElMRE0/view?usp=sharing)

When do you open solver, the first field is "Seat Goal". Our goal (or purpose) is reduce the diference between teams as minimal as possible. So we selected the cell with the diference between teams. Then we have to tell to excel that our purpose is that cell have the minimal value (chossing "min").

Then we have to tell excel wich cells they can change values to achieve our goal. In this case, Excel can change the teams of player, so we select the cells with the teams.

Last we have to tell excel whats condition (or restrictions) of this problem. The first restction is that the total of player of team 1 is tree. The total of players of team 2 is, both, 3. Then we have to tell to excel what are the limits (superior and inferior) of values of variable cells. In this case, we chose superior or equal to 1, AND (other restrction) inferior or equal to 2.

Ok. Now we have a problem with specif goal, changing the value of specifc cells, with specif restriction. Now solver can work. Then choose the method of soluction "Evolutionary", Honestly, I do know the diference between the methods, but my experience is that evolutionary method works better than the others.

I recomend reading the excel tutorial on [solver](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-Solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040). At first, all of us think that is too dificult, but believe that is simpler than it seems.

Comment: Thank you!, I have got this working for up to two teams, how would I go about figuring out multiple, I tried adding 3 more players, team counts and then thought if I took the average minus any one team this would be suitable but it seems to not know where to start.